# How to use Rx.Nex extension ForEachAsync with async action

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive, rx.net

I have code which streams data down from SQL and writes it to a different store. The code is approximately this:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from MyTable", connection))
{
     using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
     {
         var list = new List<MyData>();
         while (await reader.ReadAsync())
         {
             var row = GetRow(reader);
             list.Add(row);
             if (list.Count == BatchSize)
             {
                 await WriteDataAsync(list);
                 list.Clear();
             }
         }
         if (list.Count > 0)
         {
             await WriteDataAsync(list);
         }
     }
 }
```

I would like to use Reactive extensions for this purpose instead. Ideally the code would look like this:

```
await StreamDataFromSql()
    .Buffer(BatchSize)
    .ForEachAsync(async batch => await WriteDataAsync(batch));
```

However, it seems that the extension method ForEachAsync only accepts synchronous actions. Would it be possible to write an extension which would accept an async action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would it be possible to write an extension which would accept an async action?

Not directly.

Rx subscriptions are necessarily synchronous because Rx is a push-based system. When a data item arrives, it travels through your query until it hits the final subscription - which in this case is to execute an `Action`.

The `await`-able methods provided by Rx are `await`ing the sequence *itself* - i.e., `ForEachAsync` is asynchronous in terms of the sequence (you are asynchronously waiting for the sequence to complete), but the subscription within `ForEachAsync` (the action taken for each element) must still be synchronous.

In order to do a sync-to-async transition in your data pipeline, you'll need to have a buffer. An Rx subscription can (synchronously) add to the buffer as a producer while an asynchronous consumer is retrieving items and processing them. So, you'd need a producer/consumer queue that supports both synchronous and asynchronous operations.

The various block types in TPL Dataflow can satisfy this need. Something like this should suffice:

```
var obs = StreamDataFromSql().Buffer(BatchSize);
var buffer = new ActionBlock<IList<T>>(batch => WriteDataAsync(batch));
using (var subscription = obs.Subscribe(buffer.AsObserver()))
  await buffer.Completion;
```

Note that there is no backpressure; as quickly as `StreamDataFromSql` can push data, it'll be buffered and stored in the incoming queue of the `ActionBlock`. Depending on the size and type of data, this can quickly use a lot of memory.

Comment: Can you explain "Rx subscriptions are necessarily synchronous because Rx is a push-based system" some more? At first glance I would say that that is not correct, but maybe I've misunderstood what you're saying.

Comment: @Enigmativity I mean that there's no built-in automatic backpressure system. The subscription in your answer, for example, is synchronous, not asynchronous. As soon as the first `await` is hit in your subscription, as far as Rx is concerned the whole subscription method is already done and it's free to start another one.

Comment: Fair enough. I think I should have put in an `.ObserveOn` call to move the execution away from the UI thread. And then, depending on if `WriteDataAsync` uses any UI elements, it could just run off the UI and avoid issues about async that way.

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing to do is to use Reactive Extensions properly to get this done - so start from the point that you create the connection right up until you write your data.

Here's how:

```
IObservable<IList<MyData>> query =
    Observable
        .Using(() => new SqlConnection(""), connection =>
            Observable
                .Using(() => new SqlCommand("select * from MyTable", connection), cmd =>
                    Observable
                        .Using(() => cmd.ExecuteReader(), reader =>
                            Observable
                                .While(() => reader.Read(), Observable.Return(GetRow(reader))))))
        .Buffer(BatchSize);

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(async list => await WriteDataAsync(list));
```

I couldn't test the code, but it should work. This code assumes that `WriteDataAsync` can take a `IList<MyData>` too. If it doesn't just drop in a `.ToList()`.

Comment: `Subscribe` doesn't take a `Func<T,Task>`, so the `async` and `await` aren't really doing anything.

Comment: @ErikHeemskerk - It's still an `Action<T>` and that works with `async`/`await`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of the `ForEachAsync` method that supports asynchronous actions. It projects the source observable to a nested `IObservable<IObservable<Unit>>` containing the asynchronous actions, and then flattens it back to an `IObservable<Unit>` using the [`Merge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229099(v=vs.103)) operator. The resulting observable is finally converted to a task.

By default the actions are invoked sequentially, but it is possible to invoke them concurrently by configuring the optional `maximumConcurrency` argument.

Canceling the optional `cancellationToken` argument results to the immediate completion (cancellation) of the returned `Task`, potentially before the cancellation of the currently running actions.

Any exception that may occur is propagated through the `Task`, and causes the cancellation of all currently running actions.

```
/// <summary>
/// Invokes an asynchronous action for each element in the observable sequence,
/// and returns a 'Task' that represents the completion of the sequence and
/// all the asynchronous actions.
/// </summary>
public static Task ForEachAsync<TSource>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, CancellationToken, Task> action,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default,
    int maximumConcurrency = 1)
{
    // Arguments validation omitted
    return source
        .Select(item => Observable.FromAsync(ct => action(item, ct)))
        .Merge(maximumConcurrency)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
        .ToTask(cancellationToken);
}
```

Usage example:

```
await StreamDataFromSql()
    .Buffer(BatchSize)
    .ForEachAsync(async (batch, token) => await WriteDataAsync(batch, token));
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is [the source code for ForEachAsync](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/develop/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/QueryLanguage.Imperative.cs) and an [article](http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2009/11/15/introduction-to-the-reactive-framework-part-iv/) on the ToEnumerable and AsObservable method

We can make a wrapper around the ForEachAsync that will await a Task-returning function:

```
public static async Task ForEachAsync<T>( this IObservable<T> t, Func<T, Task> onNext )
{
    foreach ( var x in t.ToEnumerable() )
        await onNext( x );
}
```

Example usage:

```
await ForEachAsync( Observable.Range(0, 10), async x => await Task.FromResult( x ) );
```

Comment: Very good point. However, by waiting I am essentially losing the benefit of using async in the WriteDataAsync implementation. I am wondering if there is a maintain the non-blocking nature of the original code.