# safely send observable elements over awaitable tcp connection

Tags: c#, async-await, system.reactive

I have an observable which wraps a data source, which it continually watches and spits out changes as they occur:

```
IObservable<String> ReadDatasource()
{
    //returns data from the data source, and watches it for changes
}
```

and within my code I have a TCP connection

```
interface Connection
{
    Task Send(String data);
    Boolean IsAvailable { get; }
}
```

which subscribes to the observable:

```
Connection _connection;

ReadDatabase()
    .SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
    .Subscribe(
        onNext: async r =>
        {
            if (_connection.IsAvailable)
            {
                try
                {
                    await _connection.Send(r);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
           }
        }
```

If the connection is closed by the client when the observable is spitting out large volumes of data in quick succession, there are a tonne of built up tasks still awaiting (at least I think this is the case), which then throw a tonne of exceptions due to the connection not being available (the `_connection.IsAvailable` has already been checked). FWIW I do not have the ability to make changes inside the `_connection.Send(data)` method. I have no issue waiting for the `_connection.Send(data)` to complete before moving onto the next element in the observable sequence. I fact, that would probably be preferable.

Is there a simple Rx style of handling this case?

Comment: You probably need to use `Observable.Using` - it's designed to keep an `IDisposable` resource open while the observable is running and then shut down the resource when the observable ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there are a tonne of built up tasks still awaiting... which then throw a tonne of exceptions due to the connection not being available

Yes, that's what I would expect with this code. And there's nothing really *wrong* with that, since each one of those sends are in fact failing to send. If your code works fine with this, then you might just want to keep it as-is.

Otherwise...

> (the _connection.IsAvailable has already been checked).

Yes. `Connection.IsAvailable` is useless. So are `Socket.Connected` / `TcpClient.Connected`, for that matter. They're all useless because all they tell you is whether an error *has already occurred*. Which you, er, *already know* because the last call *already threw an exception*. They do *not* provide *any* guarantee or even a guess as to whether the *next* method will succeed. This is why you need [other mechanisms](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html) to detect socket connection failure.

> I have no issue waiting for the _connection.Send(data) to complete before moving onto the next element in the observable sequence. I fact, that would probably be preferable.

If `Connection` is a simple wrapper around a socket without a write queue, then you should *definitely* only perform one call to `Send` at a time. This is due to the fact that in resource-constrained scenarios (i.e., always in production, not on your dev box), a "write" operation for a socket may only write *some* of the bytes to the actual network stream. I assume your `Connection` wrapper is handling partial writes by continuing to write until the entire data buffer is sent. This works great unless the code calls `Send` multiple times - in which case you can end up with bytes being out of order (`A` and then `B` are written; `A` partially completes and the wrapper sends the rest of `A` in another write... after `B`).

So, you'll need a write queue for reliable operation. If `Connection` already provides one, then I'd say you don't need to do anything else; the multiple `Send`s failing are normal. But if `Connection` only handles sending that single data buffer and does not queue up its write requests, then you'll need to do that yourself.

This is most easily accomplished by using a TPL Dataflow block. Specifically, `ActionBlock<T>`:

```
// Define the source observable.
var obs = ReadDatabase().SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default);

// Create our queue which calls Send for each observable item.
var queue = new ActionBlock<string>(data => _connection.Send(data));

try
{
  // Subscribe the queue to the observable and (asynchronously) wait for it to complete.
  using (var subscription = obs.Subscribe(queue.AsObserver()))
    await queue.Completion;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // The first exception thrown from Send will end up here.
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Dataflow blocks understand asynchronous code, and by default they only process one item at a time. So, this code will invoke `Send` one at a time, buffering up additional data items in a FIFO queue until that `Send` completes.

Dataflow blocks have a "fail fast" behavior, so the first `Send` that throws will fault the block, causing it to discard all remaining queued writes. When the block faults, `await queue.Completion` will throw, unsubscribing from the observable and displaying the message.

If the observable completes, then `await queue.Completion` will complete, again unsubscribing from the observable, and continue execution normally.

For more about interfacing Rx with TPL Dataflow, see my [Concurrency in C# Cookbook](https://stephencleary.com/book/), recipe 7.7. You may also find [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382799/how-to-use-rx-nex-extension-foreachasync-with-async-action/45384383#45384383) helpful in understanding why passing an `async` lambda to `Subscribe` isn't ideal.

Comment: great answer. i knew the name was familiar because i already have your book! believe it or not I just opened my kindle to see where i was up to before i got distracted by "Introduction to Rx" (i needed to get up to speed in a hurry) and I'm up to "7.3 Async Wrappers for anything"