# Concurrent subscriber execution in System.Reactive

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm writing a batching pipeline that processes X outstanding operations every Y seconds. It feels like `System.Reactive` would be a good fit for this, but I'm not able to get the subscriber to execute in parallel. My code looks like this:

```
var subject = new Subject<int>();

var concurrentCount = 0;

using var reader = subject
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 100)
    .Subscribe(list => 
    {
        var c = Interlocked.Increment(ref concurrentCount);
        if (c > 1) Console.WriteLine("Executing {0} simultaneous batches", c); // This never gets printed, because Subscribe is only ever called on a single thread.
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref concurrentCount);
    });
    
Parallel.For(0, 1_000_000, i =>
{
    subject.OnNext(i);
 });
subject.OnCompleted();
```

Is there an elegant way to read from this buffered `Subject`, in a concurrent manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rx subscription code is always synchronous¹. What you need to do is to remove the processing code from the `Subscribe` delegate, and make it a side-effect of the observable sequence. Here is how it can be done:

```
Subject<int> subject = new();
int concurrentCount = 0;

Task processor = subject
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 100)
    .Select(list => Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Start(() =>
    {
        int c = Interlocked.Increment(ref concurrentCount);
        if (c > 1) Console.WriteLine($"Executing {c} simultaneous batches");
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref concurrentCount);
    })))
    .Merge(maxConcurrent: 2)
    .DefaultIfEmpty() // Prevents exception in corner case (empty source)
    .ToTask(); // or RunAsync (either one starts the processor)

for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++)
{
    subject.OnNext(i);
}
subject.OnCompleted();

processor.Wait();
```

The `Select`+`Observable.Defer`+`Observable.Start` combination converts the source sequence to an `IObservable<IObservable<Unit>>`. It's a nested sequence, with each inner sequence representing the processing of one `list`. When the delegate of the `Observable.Start` completes, the inner sequence emits a `Unit` value and then completes. The wrapping `Defer` operator ensures that the inner sequences are "cold", so that they are not started before they are subscribed. Then follows the [`Merge`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) operator, which unwraps the outer sequence to a flat `IObservable<Unit>` sequence. The `maxConcurrent` parameter configures how many of the inner sequences will be subscribed concurrently. Every time an inner sequence is subscribed by the `Merge` operator, the corresponding `Observable.Start` delegate starts running on a `ThreadPool` thread.

If you set the `maxConcurrent` too high, the `ThreadPool` may run out of workers (in other words it may become saturated), and
the concurrency of your code will then become dependent on the `ThreadPool` availability. If you wish, you can increase the number of workers that the `ThreadPool` creates instantly on demand, by using the [`ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads) method. But if your workload is CPU-bound, and you increase the worker threads above the `Environment.ProcessorCount` value, then most probably your CPU will be saturated instead.

If your workload is asynchronous, you can replace the `Observable.Defer`+`Observable.Start` combo with the `Observable.FromAsync` operator, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382799/how-to-use-rx-nex-extension-foreachasync-with-async-action/64936628#64936628).

¹ <sub>An [unpublished](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/1118) library exists, the [AsyncRx.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/tree/main/AsyncRx.NET), that plays with the idea of asynchronous subscriptions. It is based on the new interfaces `IAsyncObservable<T>` and `IAsyncObserver<T>`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, that's a great explanation, and a really good example. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You say this:

```
// This never gets printed, because Subscribe is only ever called on a single thread.
```

It's just not true. The reason nothing gets printed is because the code in the `Subscribe` happens in a locked manner - only one thread at a time executes in a `Subscribe` so you are incrementing the value and then decrementing it almost immediately. And since it starts at zero it never has a chance to rise above `1`.

Now that's just because of the Rx contract. Only one thread in subscribe at once.

We can fix that.

Try this code:

```
using var reader = subject
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 100)
    .SelectMany(list =>
        Observable
            .Start(() =>
            {
                var c = Interlocked.Increment(ref concurrentCount);
                Console.WriteLine("Starting {0} simultaneous batches", c);
            })
            .Finally(() =>
            {
                var c = Interlocked.Decrement(ref concurrentCount);
                Console.WriteLine("Ending {0} simultaneous batches", c);
            }))
    .Subscribe();
```

Now when I run it (with less than the `1_000_000` iterations that you set) I get output like this:

```
Starting 1 simultaneous batches
Starting 4 simultaneous batches
Ending 3 simultaneous batches
Ending 2 simultaneous batches
Starting 3 simultaneous batches
Starting 3 simultaneous batches
Ending 1 simultaneous batches
Ending 2 simultaneous batches
Starting 4 simultaneous batches
Starting 5 simultaneous batches
Ending 3 simultaneous batches
Starting 2 simultaneous batches
Starting 2 simultaneous batches
Ending 2 simultaneous batches
Starting 3 simultaneous batches
Ending 0 simultaneous batches
Ending 4 simultaneous batches
Ending 1 simultaneous batches
Starting 1 simultaneous batches
Starting 1 simultaneous batches
Ending 0 simultaneous batches
Ending 0 simultaneous batches
```